# Find value within a range in R

Tags: r, range, data-manipulation

My data look like below. I want to select value greater/equal to 35 and less than/equal to 350. I also want to replace those values with `withinrange`

```
value 
1  
35  
36  
37  
350  
355  
3555  
35555
```

Comment: Maybe `is.na(myVector) <- myVector > 35 & myVector < 350` or the logical complement.

Comment: or `ifelse(value>35&value<350,value,NA)`

Comment: What is `withinrange`? A vector or a constant value?

Answer (score 1):

To select the values: `value[value >= 35 & value <=350]`

To replace them with `withinrange`: `value[value >= 35 & value <=350] <- withinrange`

Comment: this command selecting   
35  
36  
37  
350  
355  
3555  
35555